# Sending a tweet from a for loop output

Tags: python, loops, tweepy

```
dict = {'57':{"number":"one","cost":"11"},'86':{"number":"two","cost":"55"},'12':{"number":"three","cost":"76"}}
for k,v in dict.items():
        print('id:',k + ',','num:' + v['number'],'cost:' +  v['cost'])
```

output:

```
id: 57, num:one cost:11
id: 86, num:two cost:55
id: 12, num:three cost:76
```

Hi, how can i send a tweet with those three output lines as they showed so if i used api.update_status() it will send 3 separated tweets

Comment: where's your tweepy code?

Answer (score 0):

Make into a single string and tweet once, Like this,

```
dict = {'57':{"number":"one","cost":"11"},'86':{"number":"two","cost":"55"},'12':{"number":"three","cost":"76"}}
data_to_tweet = '\n'.join(['id: '+k+',num: '+v['number']+' cost: '+v['cost'] for k,v in dict.items()])
tweet(data_to_tweet) #Tweeting happening here,
```